# Utilização de DTO e ViewModel em projeto ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, arquitetura-de-software, asp.net-mvc-4

Tenho um projeto ASP NET MVC 4 com os seguintes projetos:

- Domínio
- Repositório
- Contratos (interfaces)
- DTO's
- E o projeto web

O projeto web "enxerga" somente o projeto de repositório e este é responsável por executar as regras de negócio. Esse projeto sempre retorna DTO's para a camada web e na camada web (controllers) eu transformo o DTO em uma viewmodel e retorno a viewmodel para a view.

Estou utilizando DTO's porque na maioria das consultas eu não preciso de todos os dados das entidades, logo, não preciso expor toda minha entidade para a view (e também acho que não é uma boa prática).

O problema que estou vendo é que está redundante retornar um DTO para minha a camada web e na camada web transformar o DTO em viewmodel. Segue abaixo um exemplo:

Suponha que no repositório tem um método que retorna dados do usuário (login e email) pelo id:

DTO de retorno do método:

```
public class UsuarioDto{
   public string Login {get; set;}
   public string Email {get set;}
}
```

Método no repositório que retorna o usuário para a camada web

```
public class UsuarioRepositorio : IUsuarioRepository
{
   public UsuarioDto GetUsuario(int usuarioId){
      using(var context = new dbContext()) //instancia do contexto do entity
      {
          return context.Usuario.Select(x => new UsuarioDto{
                                                 Login = x.Login,
                                                 Email = x.Email
                                              }
                                       ).FirstOrDefault(x.id == usuarioId);
      }
   }
}
```

No ponto abaixo que acho que estou sendo redundante ao transformar o DTO em viewmodel

ViewModel que representa o usuário (dentro da pasta Models)

```
public class UsuarioViewModel{
   public string Login {get; set;}
   public string Email {get set;}
}
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller 
{ 
    public ActionResult User(int usuarioId)
    {
       UsuarioRepositorio usuarioRepositorio = new UsuarioRepositorio();
       var usuario = usuarioRepositorio.GetUsuario(usuarioId)
                                       .Select(x => new UsuarioViewModel{
                                                        Login = x.Login,
                                                        Email = x.Email
                                                    }
                                              );
      return View(usuario)
    }
}
```

Há uma forma de eu otimizar essa transformação de DTO para ViewModel? A impressão que tenho é que estou duplicando código, porque até onde sei, o DTO serve para trafegar dados entre as camadas e a viewmodel é utilizada para expor os dados para a view.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bom, Tiago, pelo que entendi o seu maior problema é o trabalho em transformar Modelo em DTO, depois DTO em ViewModel, ViewModel em DTO, depois DTO em Model.

Com AutoMapper, parte do trabalho seria feito e você teria menos problemas, mas antes de simplesmente utilizar uma solução do tipo, pode repensar seu modelo como um todo. Existem diversos padrões de projetos para atender necessidades parecidas com a sua, logicamente nenhum padrão é perfeito. Primeiro acho que deve pensar quais pontos são mais relevantes para você: velocidade de desenvolvimento, desacoplamento, manutenibilidade e etc.

Não existe padrão perfeito quando definimos uma arquitetura, sempre temos que abrir mão de algumas coisas para conseguir outras, não existe manutenção eficiente sem testes, desacoplamento sem separação de camadas e responsabilidades, etc.

Porque usar DTO (Data Transfer Object)? Como o próprio nome diz, objeto de transferência de dados, quando se tem um sistema onde precisa realizar diversas consultas e trazer entidades completas em consultas separadas se torna um problema, é a hora de usar um DTO.

Pelo que disse está vendo como um problema repetir esse código de transformar um objeto em outro, é o contra de usar o padrão em telas pouco complexas, um exemplo simples:

Tela de Criação de Usuário:

DTO:

```
public Guid Id {get;set;}
public string Nome {get;set;}
public string Cpf {get;set;}
public string Telefone {get;set;}
public string Email {get;set;}
public string Senha {get;set;}
```

ENTIDADE:

```
public Guid Id {get;set;}
public string Nome {get;set;}
public string Cpf {get;set;}
public string Telefone {get;set;}
public string Email {get;set;}
public string Senha {get;set;}
```

Na sua tela você vai ter que realizar validações, sua ViewModel não pode ser igual sua DTO, precisa que o usuário Confirme o E-mail e Confirme a Senha, pode precisar enviar diversas outras informações para sua tela.

Agora imagine se amanhã você perceba que é melhor separar a Entidade **Usuário** em **Pessoa Física** e **Credencial**, por qualquer motivo que seja. Sua DTO trafega os dados das duas entidades entre as camadas, continua utilizando uma única tela, não precisa alterar sua aplicação, apenas sua camada de acesso a dados.

Com algumas ferramentas como citei o AutoMapper você pode tornar seu trabalho de transformar uma entidade parecida com outra fácil, com apenas uma linha de código, e consegue aproveitar as vantagens desse padrão.

O que você precisa prezar sempre é a separação de responsabilidades e simplicidade, nem sempre menos código é o mais simples, nem sempre o mais complexo é o melhor, pondere as suas necessidades. Basicamente:

Utilize AutoMapper para converter um objeto em outro com as mesmas propriedades. Deixe sua regra de negócio no seu domínio e deixe seu repositório apenas ser o seu elo de ligação com sua base de dados. No resto tente avaliar o que fazer em cada camada, e deixe cada uma fazendo o que é de sua responsabilidade.

Answer (score 6):

> O projeto web "enxerga" somente o projeto de repositório e este é responsável por executar as regras de negócio...

O ideal é mander as regras de negócio no seu projeto de **Domínio** e não em repositório.

Repositório isola os objetos de domínio (relacionados ao negócio) de detalhes do código de acesso e mapeamento desses objetos com o banco de dados. Ou seja, ele adiciona uma camada de separação entre as camadas de acesso a dados e de domínio. Ele não deve ser responsável por executar regras de negócio.

Seu projeto web pode "exergar" seu projeto de Domínio, suas Interfaces de repositório, sem problemas.

Agora focando na sua dúvida, pelo menos para o exemplo que você colocou na pergunta eu não vejo necessiade de [DTO](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) a não ser que você faça muitas chamadas remotas para recuperar muitos dados. **Então, acredito que você pode deixar de utilizar DTO para alguns casos, onde você "não" esteja sujeito a problemas de latência inerentes à uma comunicação/consultas remotas.**

Usar DTO é interessante em casos que precisamos reduzir o número de chamadas remotas.

`Exemplo:` Você precisa fazer várias chamadas remotas, o que aumenta o tempo de resposta para além dos níveis aceitáveis. Aqui sim, interessante usar DTO, fazendo uma só consulta ao invés de várias.

> Estou utilizando DTO's porque na maioria das consultas eu não preciso de todos os dados das entidades, logo, não preciso expor toda minha entidade para a view (e também acho que não é uma boa prática).

Não fique amarrado a usar DTO apenas por esse motivo, a não ser em algum caso específico como citei.

Você pode criar um método(s) no seu Repositório que retorna as informações que serão utilizadas na View, preencher o seu objeto ViewModel (como o UsuarioViewModel do seu exemplo) e renderizar essas informações na View, sem precisar ficar convertendo DTO em ViewModel.

`Exemplo:` Você pode retornar um Usuário no seu método de Repositório e preencher seu ViewModel:

```
public class UsuarioRepositorio : IUsuarioRepository
{
   //Retorna Usuario invés de UsuarioDto
   public Usuario GetUsuario(int usuarioId){
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Deixar de usar DTO para alguns casos? Se eu não utilizar o DTO o que eu poderia usar? Retornar a minha model para a view? Neste caso acho que deveria haver um padrão pq se as vezes usar DTO e as vezes não o projeto pode ficar confuso.
Outro ponto. A minha tabela de usuário tem 15 campos. Se eu quero recuperar apenas 2 eu utilizo o DTO. Não vejo razão para retornar todas as entidades.

Comment: @TiagoCrizanto Deixar de usar DTO para alguns casos? Sim. Se eu não utilizar o DTO o que eu poderia usar? Seu repositório como exemplificado. Retornar a minha model para a view? Sim. Usando o padrão apresentado vc vai ter a redundância de fazer de/para. Aí cabe a vc verificar o que é melhor: ter padrão e ficar fazendo de/para ou usar DTO só qdo realmente necessário. Fazendo filtro (p/ não retornar todas entidades) nos métodos de repositório vc consegue filtrar os campos/entidades que quizer, não precisa de DTO só para isso. Pode ficar confuso se vc não entender qdo realmente deve-se usar DTO.