# Onde colocar um objeto que não é entidade no DDD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ddd

Meu projeto em ASP.NET MVC em C# possui uma camada de Dominio onde tenho as entidades, e as regras de negocio.
Preciso adicionar uma nova regra onde devo retornar um objeto com uma lista interna, porém acabei tendo uma discussão sobre regras do DDD com meus colegas e alguns defendem a tese de que este objeto mesmo sendo utilizado por rotinas do Dominio, não pode ficar no Dominio.

Então passei a utilizar o dynamic, mas ao chegar no automapper o mesmo apresenta problemas para a conversão.

Gostaria de saber a opinião de quem tem mais experiencia com DDD, ou quem possa sugerir um projeto, ideia ou solução para este problema.

Exemplo:

```
A Estrutura é a seguinte:
1) Web
     Automaper
     View (Com Entidades do banco de dados e outas)     
2) Application
3) Domain
    Entites (Entidades do banco de dados)
    Services (Onde ficam as regras de negocios)
4) Repository 
    Dapper
    Entites Repository
5)Ioc
```

Agora preciso criar uma rotina que calcule determinadas informações
isso eu fiz no 3) Domain -> Service "FluxoService", dentro tenho o metodo que retorna uma lista tipo "Fluxo"
Então "Fluxo" não é uma entidade e não persiste no banco de dados, este objeto "Fluxo" pode ficar no domain?

Se Não pode, como eu posso retornar os dados deste tipo "Fluxo"?

Outro exemplo: Fiz um select usando dapper (4)Repository o retorno deste select eu criei uma classe chamada "MeusDados"
Para retornar para a 1) Web vou precisar passar pelo 3)Domain -> Service (MeusDadosService chama MeusDadosRepository((4) Repository)
como eu posso retornar "MeusDados" para a camada 1) Web se a Classe "MeusDados" não puder ser colocada em domain?

Talvez a solução seria utilizar subdomain? alguêm utiliza com a estrutura semelhante a minha? ou para utilizar terei que mudar a estrutura?

outro exemplo: [MusicStoreDDD](https://github.com/thiagolunardi/MvcMusicStoreDDD) 
Neste projeto Cart é uma entidade e estrá no Domain
Agora quero adicionar Fluxo e FluxoService que não são entidades e não persistem

Estas podem ficar no domain?

```
public class CartService : Service<Cart>, ICartService
{
    public CartService(ICartRepository repository, ICartReadOnlyRepository readOnlyRepository) 
        : base(repository, readOnlyRepository)
    {
    }
}

public class FluxoService : IFluxoService
{
    private readonly ICartService _service;

    public CartService(ICartRepository repository, ICartReadOnlyRepository readOnlyRepository, ICartService service) 
        : base(repository, readOnlyRepository)
    {
        _service = service; 
    }

    public List<Fluxo> ProcessarFluxo()
    {
        return new List<Fluxo>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Você tem uma `entity` que irá consumir o essa nova regra. Essa nova regra refere-se a regra de negócio ou apenas uma  formatação do dado para exibição? Essa lista que será retornada será usado por uma  `entity` específica ou por todas? Essa regra irá fazer validações? Essa nova regra dependerá de outros serviços? Preciso desses detalhes para te ajudar

Comment: `Onde colocar um objeto (...)` ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: Editei a pergunta e adicionei outras informações

Comment: @nfrigo da uma olhada você pode usar DTO para fazer o que você quer no seu repositorio https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33005/utiliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-dto-e-viewmodel-em-projeto-asp-net-mvc

Comment: A estrutura de comunicação é 1) Web -> Chama 2) Aplication (Aqui tem as transações) -> chama o 3) service (regras de negocio) ->chama 4) Repository, o retorno dos dados faz o caminho inverso 4,3,2,1.  Então não posso chamar o repository ou o service da camada web, mas obrigado @EduardoSampaio

Comment: então na camada web vai ter uma viewmodel que vai esperar tudo você precisa que vai enviar para onde você quiser .

Comment: mas onde coloco o DTO, este pode ficar no dominio?

Answer (score 2):

Separando as coisas:

- Seu objeto de Domínio deve resolver um problema de negócio
- Seu objeto AutoMapper (deve estar em outra camada) evita a necessidade de escrever extensos códigos de mapeamento, assim proporcionando mais agilidade no desenvolvimento e facilitando a manutenção.

Até onde eu sei o AutoMapper sabe mapear um objeto para outro mas não sabe (e nem deve) sobre suas regras de negócio para criar seu objeto de domínio. Ou seja, não é ele que vai resolver uma lógica de negócio para trazer um objeto com ou sem a lista interna.

Para saber se sua nova regra deve ou não ser implementada no Domínio faça a seguinte análise: é uma regra de negócio?

Partindo então do princípio que seja uma regra de negócio você pode tratar a criação desse objeto no próprio objeto via um construtor, um método ou usando o conceito de *Factory* do DDD (quando esse objeto é muito complexo, que a princípio não parece ser).

Exemplo:

No objeto que você deseja retornar, conforme os parâmetros informados, seja no construtor ou em um método, execute a lógica e retorne um novo objeto com ou sem a lista interna.

```
public class Objeto()
{
    public static Objeto NovoObjeto(bool comListaInterna)
    {
        if(comListaInterna)
        {
            // return Objeto com lista interna
        }
        // return Objeto sem lista interna
    }
}
```

Porém, caso essa regra de negócio não dependa apenas das informações da sua Entidade, mas também de serviços externos e repositórios, invés de implementar essas chamadas na entidade, você deve utilizar o que o conceito de *Services* do DDD que é uma classe que resolve problemas de negócio mas não são uma "responsabilidade natural" de entidades nem objetos de valor.

Comment: Editei a pergunta e adicionei outras informações

Comment: Cuidado com a edição de pergunta adicionando mais perguntas, se você reler a pergunta vai perceber que ela agora depois da edição tem umas 5 perguntas rsrsrs. Ela agora está gigante, te aconselho a reeditar e deixar como estava. Depois abrir outras perguntas. Assim minha resposta ficou mais adequada somente a sua primeira dúvida.

Answer (score 0):

A camada Domínio no DDD onde fica todas suas regras de negócio não deve ter nenhum tipo de tecnologia acoplada.

Mas respondendo sua pergunta se pelo que eu entendi onde você vai ter um objeto complexo onde vai retornar uma lista:

Exemplo:

```
   class Pessoa
    {
        public int PessoaId { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
    }


    class Produto
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
    }
```

mas agora se você necessita fazer um acesso ao banco não vai poder fazer nessa camada.O problema do autommaper pode fazer DTO na camada de acesso Banco no caso Infra.Data e retornar sua necessidade dentro desse novo objeto.

Comment: Editei a pergunta e adicionei outras informações